# "/me/feed?since=" set this 'since' to the updated time in stead of the created time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, timestamp

I have a application that monitors a businesspage for you, along with other sources like [Twitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter). For the purpose of internal comments and analytics I store the posts on the wall in our database.

Every 10 minutes I ask Facebook if there are new posts since the last time. I use "/me/feed?since=[10 mitutes ago]". The problem is when I have already stored the post and a new comment is added to this post, when I request the new posts this post is not returned.

I know this is because the created time is before the timestamp requested in the since call. But the updated time is not. Is there a way to set 'since' to the updated time in stead of the created time?

*Extra case information*

I also tried this using FQL instead of [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API). But that method has a problem/bug.

I use this script on the pages of very large companies, like [Heineken](http://www.facebook.com/heineken). On these pages, there are a few posts per hour and on busy times many posts per minute. But those are not the problem.

The problem is that I have a few posts, usually one or two a day, that are very interesting and have a lot of comments, and continue to have comments for days. Those 'large' posts are the most interesting of all, but they get suppressed out of my results because there are too many new posts.

Comment: afaik there is not words in the facebook doc about to set since to updated_time /created_time

Answer (score 0):

Use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/):

```
SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND updated_time > YOUR_TIME_LIMIT
```

This gives you all posts to a user's wall (source_id = me()) which were updated after a certain time. The "updated_time" is changed when a user comments on the post.

To add fields to retrieve with the query, please have a look at the fields in the FQL [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table.

Comment: I have tried it that way but there is a bug in the updated_time column of the stream table. It does not give the right results back

Comment: Do you use Unix timestamp for updated_time? If you do, test your timestamp is correct by converting it back to a date. Does your timestamp have the same number of trailing zeros and total number of digits as a FB timestamp? On an Android app I did I had to divide the timestamp from Java Date by 1000 to meet FB's format.

Comment: Rather than sending a request every 10 minutes you should also consider using the real time api. This will notify you whenever there are updates.

Comment: @GunnarKarlsson yes, i use a Unix timestamp. I added extra info about the problem. Because updated_time is not indexable, the 'n' results who where last created only get filtered by updated_time (i think 'n' is 100). But i need the 'n' results to be the last updated.

Comment: @IngaH I was under the assumption that the realtime updates did not work great. Could you answer two questions about it. One, how those realtime updates treat the comments on a message? Two, i also use the same script for some small companies, is it smart tho use realtime updates for those?